# How to get a link preview in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I have made an app in slack where I want to fetch details of a document from an API and then display the preview of the same file in slack. I'm using Nodejs for the app but how do I get a document or link preview in slack while using Nodejs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For unfurling links/media when posting using `chat.postMessage`,

 you can make use of below mentioned 'optional argurments'

> ***unfurl_links*** Pass true to enable unfurling of primarily text-based content.
> https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_unfurl_links

> ***unfurl_media*** Pass false to disable unfurling of media content.
> https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_unfurl_media

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage